# Do book scorpions 'pinch' or 'sting'?

Tags: word-choice

Snakes, spiders, and other creatures with venomous fangs are said to bite rather than sting when they use their venom. Does the same apply to other venomous organs: for example, most book scorpions have venomous pincers.

Would an attack using such an appendage be deemed a 'pinch' (or whatever a similar attack from a crab or scorpion would be called) as a snake's attack would be called a bite, or would 'sting' be more appropriate for the context of a venomous pincer?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as the details of how the pincers deliver their venom is not addressed and therefore it is not possible to answer.

Comment: @Greybeard Then why did you answer it? (Honestly wondering, maybe that isn't frowned upon on ELU.)

Comment: @Joachim It should be obvious that although I think the question should be closed, others might not. My decision is not binding on anyone. The question remains open until the required number of votes is reached. You will note that I have not offered a verb.

Comment: @Greybeard - Unfortunately the mention of pseudoscorpions has thrown this entire question off kilter.  The question could be better worded, *If venom is delivered via a pincher (like a lobster's or scorpion's) would that be considered a bite or a sting?*

Comment: For reference, here is the Wikipedia article on [pseudoscorpions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscorpion), aka book scorpions or false scorpions. It might be usefully included in the question.

Comment: @EllieK - I have deleted my last answer - it was my ignorance. The questions stands, although the OP should have explained what, I hope, my answer explains, i.e. how the pseudoscorpion's venomous pincers work and hence the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding book scorpions: a chapter in the book *Scorpion Venoms* [calls it a "sting."](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-94-007-6404-0_11) An article from Utah State [prefers "inject venom into"](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1944&context=extension_curall) but also notes that they "cannot bite people."

In short: I haven't been able to find a precise convention about what term to use. This is likely a result of their unusual way of delivering venom. Furthermore, the fact that they do not bite humans means that there has been little need to create precise terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my last answer - apparently, "book scorpions" are a thing! I had only ever heard of them as pseudoscorpions.

They do have venomous pincers - pedipalps, otherwise known as chelal hands.

The verb is "**inject**"

There is a paper: [Venom collection and analysis in the pseudoscorpion Chelifer cancroides (Pseudoscorpiones: Cheliferidae) Jonas Krämer 1, Hans Pohl 2, Reinhard Predel 3 2019](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30796931/), which has

> These experiments first required a morphological investigation of the venom delivery system with a focus on the role of the lamina defensor in the release of venom. Likely, the venom delivery system of pseudoscorpions has a mechanism that prevents the release of venom *if the prey is not successfully penetrated by a venom tooth*. Electrical stimulation of a gland-containing chelal hand in combination with a mechanical stimulation of the lamina defensor at the base of the venom tooth resulted in an average of 5 nl of collected venom.

Apparently, the paper (behind a paywall) also has

> “Pseudoscorpions **inject** venom through the tips of the pedipalpal chela, with their venom glands located in the pedipalpal fingers or sometimes extending into the base of the chelal hand (Figure 1c).”

Answer (score 0):

From the [University of Minnesota](https://extension.umn.edu/insect-relatives/pseudoscorpions) -

> Poison glands in the pseudoscorpion pincers help to paralyze prey.

I think that suggests the pseudoscorpion's pincer is a **stinger**.

By the same logic one could argue that a viper's fang is also a stinger.  It just so happens that the stinger is located in the snake's mouth.